# C++ bitset strange value

Tags: c++, printf, bitset

```
#include <bitset>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    bitset<128> bs(42);
    bs[11]=0;
    bs[12]=1;
    assert(bs[12]==1);
    printf("bs[11]=%d\n", bs[11]);
    printf("bs[12]=%d\n", bs[12]);
    return 0;
}
```

console output:
[image]

Why can't I simply get 0 or 1 as output ?

Comment: `%d` is for `int`s, whereas `bitset::operator[]` returns a `bitset::reference`. You can use `std::cout` (which is anyway a more modern c++ mechanism) to print a bitset element.

Comment: ps. If you paste your code here: https://cpp.sh/ you'll see the related warnings.

Comment: Turn up the compiler warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/j7qMMj1cG You can add `!= 0` or a cast to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Clang returns a compiler error - you can't pass a bitset::reference into a variadic function.

Comment: Compiler finds the problem when warnings are enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/W37Ef5hWG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` with `%d` is for integer values, whereas [`std::bitset::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) returns a `std::bitset::reference`.

You can use `std::cout` from `<iostream>` header (which is anyway a more c++ "way" to print to the console):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<128> bs(42);
    bs[11] = 0;
    bs[12] = 1;
    assert(bs[12] == 1);
    std::cout << "bs[11]=" << bs[11] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bs[12]=" << bs[12] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bs[11]=0
bs[12]=1
```

A side note: better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Ok, but this answer doesn't explain why the overload of `std::bitset::operator[]` returning a `bool` isn't [chosen](https://godbolt.org/z/1sEbvavKv), though.

Comment: @Bob__ interesting point. I am actually not sure. Perhaps you care to explain? In any case I believe my answer solves the OP's issue (plus steer them in the right direction of using iostream instead of printf).

Comment: I guess it depends on `std::printf` accepting a variadic list of *non* const parameters vs [`std::cout::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) having an overload accepting a `bool`. I'm *not* a language lawyer, so please don't trust me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ then don't call `printf` to output something (my compiler refuse to compile your code correctly).
This C++ code works correctly using `iostream`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    std::bitset<128> bs(42);
    bs[11]=0;
    bs[12]=1;
    std::cout << "bs[11]=" << bs[11] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bs[12]=" << bs[12] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's also the new `std::format` stuff.

Comment: @Spencer Adding an answer on the duplicate target that shows how to use `std::format` to do the task would be useful.

Comment: @Spencer `format` is C++20. Not so many programmers are using this version (don't know).

Answer (score 2):

With some review comments :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

// anything with a .h extension is probably "C" not "C++"
// #include <assert.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
// using namespace std; <== NO, don't use using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::bitset<128> bs(42);
    bs[11]=0;
    bs[12]=1;

    assert(bs[12]==1);

    std::cout <<"bs[11]" << bs[11] << "\n";
    std::cout << "bs[12]" << bs[11] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```